# Popping up windows from a SharePoint webpart

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, popup

I'm trying to pop a window up, from inside a procedure running in SharePoint. I need to pass a parameter to the URL, and have been trying to run the following, however, the popup never pops up.

```
string sURL="http://myserver/mypage.aspx?param1=abc";
Response.Write("script LANGUAGE=\"Javascript\">\n");
Response.Write("window.open(\""+sUrl +"\", \"\", \"width=300, height=100\")");
Response.Write("<//script");
```

Can you help ?

Cheers

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Your opening script tag is missing a < (opening angle bracket.).
- You don't need the \n at the end of that line.
- Your window.open command should have a ; at the end. (For completeness.)
- Your closing script tag does not need a double //
- Your closing script tag needs a closing > bracket. (Thanks OedipusPrime)

I believe that should fix it, it was probably the opening angle bracket which was the problem.
However you should probably use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx).

As the above poster stated, the script you're attempting to write out has various errors (you're also missing a > in the closing script tag), but more importantly you should be using the ASP.Net object model for injecting the Javascript on the page.